# How to remove lines in txt file that are over 140 characters long?

Tags: windows, text-editing

I want to import a ton of tweets to Twitter from a txt file but some of the lines are over 140 characters long. How can I remove the lines that are over 140 characters long? I am using Windows 7.

Thanks!

Comment: windows 7 is not a text editor, so you can't do that with it. You need a text editor like Notepad++ or Word. Do you want to delete them from the file or split to multiple lines?

Comment: I know Windows 7 is not a text editor, I just added that so people would not suggest solutions that work on Linux. I want to delete all lines that are over 140 char long.

Comment: What tools do you have? Notepad++, Word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think so you can do this with Windows default notepad. If you can install notepad++ you can do this very easily by following below steps:

1. Install notepad++ latest version and open text file which contains data
2. Press Ctrl+F and navigate to "Mark" tab
3. In the Find what input box, type **.{140,}**
4. Check **Bookmark line**
5. Select **Regular Expression** radio button under search mode
6. Go to **Search** menu, look for bookmark (2nd last option).
7. Select **Remove Bookmarked Lines**

Comment: Might be easier to immediately replace `^.{140,}$` with empty lines, I think?